# Angular 2 put HTML into tag

Tags: http, angular

I tried to put HTML content in a tag.
The div tag displays a page. But script tag doesn't work.
Looks this code...

```
getRequestToAssignPage (param: string) : any {
    return this.$http.get(param)
        .map((res: Response) => {
            this.status = res;
            return res.text()
        })
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => this.response = response)
        .catch(error => this.status = error);

}
```

That's method make a request with get a new page, and convert it to text.
Then i put text to the div tag.
Like this.

```
<div [innerHTML]="response"></div>
```

it works! page is display, but script tags doesn't work, and it displays how the text.
After page was load, below content belong the text

> jQuery(document).ready(function () { jQuery('#filter-form').yiiActiveForm([], []); jQuery('#id-vendors-list').yiiGridView({"filterUrl":"/vendors/vendor/index","filterSelector":"#w0-filters input, #w0-filters select"}); });

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a problem with the safe HTML.

Try implementing this pipe:

```
import { Injectable, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
@Injectable()
export class SafePipe {
   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
   transform(url) {
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
}
```

And then:

```
<div [innerHTML]="response | safe"></div>
```